# Import Maven projects automatically checkbox dissapear in IntelliJ EAP

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

[image: Print Screen]

I use to use IntelliJ, lately I have updated to IntelliJ EAP now the checkbox "Import Maven projects automatically" has dissapeard , so every time I add a new dependecy I need to do it manually.Is there any other way or work around to have this checkbox visible again , or to enable auto import?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Search "Enable auto-reload after any changes" in the action dialog.

They have renamed and relocated the functionality to the Maven tool window as a control with the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

By following ways you can Import `Maven` projects automatically:

For `InteliJ IDEA 14` upwards:

```
Click Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing -> TICK "Import Maven projects automatically".
```

For `InteliJ IDEA 2020` upwards:

```
Click Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> TICK "Reload projects after changes in the build scripts" and "Any changes"
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

They have added now in build tools -> select Any changes for reload project after changes in the build scripts.

Answer (score 1):

"We’ve also removed the option to enable/disable auto-import from the settings, as the improvements mentioned above have made it redundant."

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/01/intellij-idea-2020-1-eap/?_ga=2.209144210.1862481759.1584865190-1304159286.1579103926#maven_and_gradle_importing_updates

Answer (score 0):

Press `ctrl` + `shift` + `a` to open the "actions" dialog.
From there, type "import maven projects automatically". Click that option and it should work.